# How do I validate a SAML assertion in Perl?

Tags: perl, saml

I need to validate a SAML assertion of this kind:

```
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="Assertion-uuide824d44-0134-14b1-8e70-f85c710cb043" IssueInstant="2011-12-05T13:55:47Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">MPS</saml:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="uuide824d48-0134-18fe-b37b-f85c710cb043">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
            <ds:Reference URI="#Assertion-uuide824d44-0134-14b1-8e70-f85c710cb043">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <xc14n:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:xc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs saml xsi"></xc14n:InclusiveNamespaces>
                    </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
                <ds:DigestValue>p02xKMDUYCR5xpppYUOQgsGBR5c=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>R9YHo8TK/wYkGkTP3QrnnM8U6TKf9vu+ElpRjDPgpg4O88oARZSb9OhlVn2sXJGEaQ5i0ORrofbKwOI+D/jFgz3Hz/g/h4yt2aqIFxLpOTFb448bDvFsHHWAoWc0DUPYf1AjW7Peu1ICSCdR3EaVLqtgdsUsVWoA7oXbWyAyVLM=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:KeyValue>
                <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                    <ds:Modulus>iZ0D1X6rk8+ZwNBTVZt7C85m421a8A52Ksjw40t+jNvbLYDp/W66AMMYD7rB5qgniZ5K1p9W8ivM9WbPxc2u/60tFPg0e/Q/r/fxegW1K1umnay+5MaUvN3p4XUCRrfg79OvurvXQ7GZa1/wOp5vBIdXzg6i9CVAqL29JGi6GYU=</ds:Modulus>
                    <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
                </ds:RSAKeyValue>
            </ds:KeyValue>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml:Subject>
        <saml:NameID Format="urn:ibm:names:ITFIM:5.1:accessmanager">J006068</saml:NameID>
        <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"></saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2011-12-05T13:45:47Z" NotOnOrAfter="2011-12-05T14:05:47Z">
        <saml:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">1030</saml>
```

I did not find a library on CPAN that can take the SAML as argument and can validate it.

Someone can help me with how to reach my goal?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, better late than never... how to use it...

When you say 'validate' I'm not sure if you mean 'check the assertion', or 'verify the signature'.

```
my $assertion = Net::SAML2::Protocol::Assertion->new_from_xml( 
   xml => decode_base64($saml_response)
);
```

then you just check the validity of the Assertion object created via the accessors. I'm assuming you understand SAML semantics.

To verify the signature, you need access to the private key:

```
my $sig = Net::SAML2::XML::Sig->new( { key =>'/private.key' } );
$sig->verify( $xml );
```

See the XML::Sig perldoc for variations on the source of the key (x509, certs).

Note that Net::SAML2 doesn't cover encrypted SAML assertions () but you didn't ask about that.

Answer (score 1):

The Net::SAML2 CPAN module would help you out here

http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SAML2

Comment: there's no documentation about how to use it :-(